# Swift: append into dictionary return random

Tags: arrays, swift, xcode, dictionary

I use this code :

```
AppDelegate.monthList = [Int: String]()
for index in stride(from: 1, to: 12, by: 1) {
    AppDelegate.monthList[index] = "\(index)"
}

print("iosLog MONTH: \(AppDelegate.monthList)")
```

And result is :

> iosLog MONTH: [11: "11", 10: "10", 2: "2", 4: "4", 9: "9", 5: "5", 6:
>   "6", 7: "7", 3: "3", 1: "1", 8: "8"]

Whay ?!

I want add respectively the keys ( like `PHP` or `Java` )

Comment: Dictionary in swift doesn't have order. Saving and retrieval are based on keys. You can use `AppDelegate.monthList.sort( $0.0 < $1.0)` which will return you an array of tuples in the ascending order of Int keys.

Comment: @abhi1992 thank you. i get this error for $0.0 `Anonymous closure argument not contained in a closure`

Comment: Or insert the month list into an array, you will have the strings in right order and month number will be index + 1

Comment: @ComputerIm , use`AppDelegate.monthList.sort { $0.0 < $1.0 }` . Sort function is a closure with two parameters. In this case each parameter is a tuple of type `(Int,String)` . You will get the array like [(1,"1"),(2,"2")....etc]

Comment: @abhi1992 thank you. i have to change all codes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because [Dictionary](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/dictionary) is *unordered* collection:

> Every dictionary is an unordered collection of key-value pairs.

So, if you are aiming to get a sorted version of it, you should -logically- transform it into ordered collection, which is array. You could get:

Sorted array of `AppDelegate.monthList` keys:

```
let sortedkeys = AppDelegate.monthList.keys.sorted()
// [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]
```

Sorted array of `AppDelegate.monthList` values:

```
let sortedValues = AppDelegate.monthList.values.sorted()
// [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]
```

Or sorted array of tuples, as `[(key, value)]`:

```
let sortedTuples = AppDelegate.monthList.sorted(by: <)

for tuple in sortedTuples {
    print("\(tuple.key): \(tuple.value)")
}
```